# Why is my window not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Just finished coding this but for some reason when I run it, my window won't show at all! Anyone have any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RetailPriceCalculator extends JFrame
{
private InputPanel inputs;
private OutputPanel outputs;
private ExplanationPanel banner;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton calcButton;
private JButton exitButton;

public void RetailPriceCalculatorGUI()
{
    setTitle("Retail Price Calculator");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    banner = new ExplanationPanel();
    inputs = new InputPanel();
    outputs = new OutputPanel();

    buildButtonPanel();

    add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(inputs, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(outputs, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public void buildButtonPanel()
{
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

    buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
    buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
}

private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        double wholesale, markup, retail;

        wholesale = inputs.getWholesale();
        markup = inputs.getMarkup();

        retail = wholesale * (1 + markup);

        outputs.setRetail(retail);
    }
}

private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new RetailPriceCalculator();
    } 

}
```

The `ExplanationPanel()`, `InputPanel()`, and `OutputPanel()` classes are simple and shouldn't get in the way of the code. I just run it, than it all of a sudden says it's terminated, and no window, at all! Not even an empty frame!

Comment: Try assigning a reference in the main block like this `RetailPriceCalculator pc = new RetailPriceCalculator();`

Comment: RetailPriceCalculatorGUI should be the constructor RetailPriceCalculator that will build the panels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem you are having typo in `RetailPriceCalculator` method.

Change `public void RetailPriceCalculatorGUI()` to constructor `public RetailPriceCalculator()`

or update your main method to:

```
new RetailPriceCalculator().RetailPriceCalculatorGUI();
```

Comment: That was it :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You code has no executable constructor (only the default constructor, which isn't doing anything for you)

Based on what I can tell from you code, you want to change `public void RetailPriceCalculatorGUI() {` to `public RetailPriceCalculator() {`

Having said, I encourage you to avoid extending directly from top level containers like `JFrame`, you're locking yourself into a single use case and you're not adding any new/reusable functionality to the class.  Better to start with a `JPanel` and build up the UI from then add it to what ever container you want